# Using Git With Eclipse Remote Systems Explorer

Tags: eclipse, git, cfeclipse

I am doing web development using CFEclipse with Classic Eclipse (Indigo) on a Windows Server.

I am using Remote Systems Explorer to access a Linux box via sftp.

The Linux box has Git installed.  There is one branch in the development folder.

I have installed EGit in Eclipse, but there are no provisions for working with a remote system.

Because I cannot develop locally, how should I checkout files, edit and review changes in a browser, and ultimately commit properly?  There is no local repository and checking out files through ssh (putty) while editing them in Eclipse does not show my changes when browsed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can access to the remote location through ssh why you don't just simply clone the repository in local and then pull and push the changes ?

I think that cloning the the repository is the best bet in your situation, you have only to install [msysgit](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/) on your windows machine ...

Comment: My concern here is that I will have to push my changes to the dev repository from my local repository whenever I want to see my code in a browser.  I would not be able to run the code that exists in my local windows repository because of differences in file structures.  What does using msysgit give me but an extra step of an unusable local repository?

Comment: The better solution in my opinion remain clone the repository and pull and push the changes that is a simple and quick step ...

Comment: I understand that the best answer is 'use Git the way that it should be used, developing in a local repository that mirrors the environment the web code will ultimately run in.'  I don't understand if you are saying that there is an easier way to do that or not.  Or if your answer is saying to do that in the first place.

Comment: Do that because is the best way in my opinion, maybe you can find another way, but the standard way smoothest ...

Comment: This is not a good approach. What I think davidj is trying to accomplish is to have his dev box on a remote server. This means, change and test in a remote server. Thats the meaning of RSE. What you are proposing is a good idea if you have your dev box locally. This means all environment locally. But this is different and I think this is not what he needs. In order to test the changes he made locally in the remote dev server, he has to commit, push and pull to get the code remotely. He cannot test remotely unstaged changes.

Comment: It's not always possible to work on a project on your local machine. One can easily imagine code that is meant to run in a particular environment. You might be able to imitate that environment on your local machine, but it's kind of an extra step to first develop on your own computer totally removed from the real dev environment, and then push your work onto a dev server where you should have been testing in the first place.
I too was hoping that Eclipse could pick up on Git repos in RSE, but it's looking like that is not currently possible...

Answer (score 0):

You can use remote project to achieve what you need. Unfortunately, git operations need to be done on the remote server. But, you can change the files and the files will be changed remotely on fly. To create the remote project you have to right click on the remote folder you want to create the remote project. The context menu you will find "Create Remote Project".

What Eclipse will do is make the modification thru RSE. This means, eclipse will deal with save files remotely.